# Can someone explain to expression $(n+1) + 2^k - 2^{k-1}$ was simplified to $(n+1) + 2^{k-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Need help to understand how we simplified the following:
$$(n+1) + 2^k - 2^{k-1}$$ was simplified to $$(n+1) + 2^{k-1}$$
I know it is the basic algebra, but I am stuck. Thanks :(

Comment: $2^k = 2\cdot 2^{k-1} = 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-1}\ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$2^k = 2\cdot2^{k-1} = 2^{k-1} + 2^{k-1}$$
so $2^k - 2^{k-1} = 2^{k-1}$. The rest should be clear.

Answer (score 3):

$ 2^k-2^{k-1}=2^{k-1}(2-1)=2^{k-1}$

Answer (score 2):

$2^{k-1}=2^k 2^{-1}$ (exp laws) So $2^k-2^{k-1}=2^k-2^k 2^{-1}$ Then by commun factor $2^k-2^k 2^{-1}=2^k (1-2^{-1})=2^k (1-1/2)=2^k (1/2)=2^k  2^{-1}=2^{k-1}$

**Note that:** $2^{-1}=1/2$.

So $(n+1)+2^k-2^{k-1}=(n+1)+2^{k-1}$

I hope I could help ypu ;)